# Proving Binary Tree Properties

Tags: binary-tree, computer-science, coq, proof-general

As an exercise for myself, I'm trying to define and prove a few properties on binary trees.

Here's my btree definition:

```
Inductive tree : Type :=
| Leaf
| Node (x : nat) (t1 : tree) (t2 : tree).
```

The first property I wanted to prove is that the height of a btree is at least `log2(n+1)` where `n` is the number of nodes. So I defined `countNodes` trivially:

```
Fixpoint countNodes (t : tree) :=
  match t with
  | Leaf => 0
  | Node _ t1 t2 => 1 + (countNodes t1) + (countNodes t2)
  end.
```

And `heightTree`:

```
Fixpoint heightTree (t : tree) :=
  match t with
  | Leaf => 0
  | Node _ t1 t2 => 1 + (max (heightTree t1) (heightTree t2))
  end.
```

Now, here's my (incomplete) theorem. Could anyone provide me with hints on how to complete this induction? It seems like I should have 2 base cases (`Leaf` and `Node _ Leaf Leaf`), how can I do that?

```
Theorem height_of_tree_is_at_least_log2_Sn : forall t : tree,
    log2 (1 + (countNodes t)) <= heightTree t.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction t.
  - simpl. rewrite Nat.log2_1. apply le_n.
  -
```

Remaining goal:

```
1 goal (ID 26)
  
  x : nat
  t1, t2 : tree
  IHt1 : log2 (1 + countNodes t1) <= heightTree t1
  IHt2 : log2 (1 + countNodes t2) <= heightTree t2
  ============================
  log2 (1 + countNodes (Node x t1 t2)) <= heightTree (Node x t1 t2)
```

PS: I have a similar problem when trying to prove that the degree of any node can only be 0, 1, or 2. Also issues on the inductive step.

Comment: A [btree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is something different than a binary tree.

Comment: How does the proof go on paper? If you want to consider the case of `Node _ Leaf Leaf` separately, you can do `case t1` and `case t2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your proof start. If you simplify your second sub-goal with `simpl in *`, you obtain:

```
1 goal (ID 47)
  
  x : nat
  t1, t2 : tree
  IHt1 : Nat.log2 (S (countNodes t1)) <= heightTree t1
  IHt2 : Nat.log2 (S (countNodes t2)) <= heightTree t2
  ============================
  Nat.log2 (S (S (countNodes t1 + countNodes t2))) <=
  S (Init.Nat.max (heightTree t1) (heightTree t2))
```

In order to make things more readable, you replace expressions which refer to trees with variables (with `remember`for instance):

```
1 goal (ID 59)
  
  x : nat
  t1, t2 : tree
  n1, n2, p1, p2 : nat
  IH1 : Nat.log2 (S n1) <= p1
  IH2 : Nat.log2 (S n2) <= p2
  ============================
  Nat.log2 (S (S (n1 + n2))) <= S (Init.Nat.max p1 p2)
```

It's now a goal about `log2`and `max`.  Many properties on `log2` are in the standard library. The `lia` tactic is very helpful for dealing with `max`.

About your question on degree of nodes:
How do you formalize your statement ? Is it as follows ?

```
Fixpoint Forallsubtree (P : tree -> Prop) t :=
  match t with
    Leaf => P t
  | Node x t1 t2 => P t /\ Forallsubtree P t1 /\ Forallsubtree P t2
  end.

Definition root_degree (t: tree) :=
  match t with Leaf => 0 | Node _ _ _ => 2 end. 

Goal forall t,
  Forallsubtree (fun t =>  0 <= root_degree t <= 2) t.  
induction t; cbn; auto.    
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the very instructive reply, Pierre. I didn't know about `remember`, it's very useful indeed. I'm yet to complete the proof, but getting there, I hope. The formalization of the degree of the nodes is as follows:

```
Definition degreeTree (t : tree) :=
  match t with
  | Leaf             => 0
  | Node _ Leaf Leaf => 0
  | Node _ _    Leaf => 1
  | Node _ Leaf _    => 1
  | Node _ _    _    => 2
  end.

Theorem every_node_has_degree_0_1_2 : forall t : tree,
    degreeTree t = 0 \/ degreeTree t = 1 \/ degreeTree t = 2.
```

Comment: Perhaps your statement of `every_node_has_degree_0_1_2` describes a property of the degree of the root of a tree (and not of all the nodes of this tree).

With your definition of `degreeTree`you can easily prove the following statement (with a few case analyses).
```
forall t, Forallsubtree (fun t =>  0 <= degreeTree t <= 2) t.

```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with reading Mathcomp/SSReflect, take a look at this lemma:

https://github.com/clayrat/fav-ssr/blob/trunk/src/bintree.v#L102-L108

Your theorem can be then derived as a corollary:

```
Corollary log_h_geq t : log2n (size1_tree t) <= height t.
Proof.
rewrite -(exp2nK (height t)); apply: leq_log2n.
by exact: exp_h_geq.
Qed.
```